# WordPressテンプレート化でsingle.phpを認識してくれません。

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

WordPressを始めました。

しかも超初心者で、HTML、CSS、PHP等Web環境もいまいち理解できていない状況です。
でも何とか頑張ってやっています。

さて本題です。
他Webサイトを参考にしながら、HTMLとCSSで制作されたサイトの一部を
WordPressに置き換えて、WordPressで記事を書き換えできるよう
仕様変更をしています。

他Webサイトの指示通り、

> footer.php、header.php、index.php、sidebar.php、single.php、style.css

というようにHTMLのファイルを分割して`style.css`も適切に書き換えました。

やりたいことは、

> WordPressの`ダッシュボード`にある`固定ページ`で入力した 内容を上記のテンプレート化した`single.php`に反映をさせたい

のです。

なぜなら、参考中のWebサイトに

> 固定ページで入力した内容は`sigle.php`で表示される

と記載があったからです。

参考中のWebサイトよると、

> index.phpよりsingle.phpの方が優先して表示 される

ようにWordPressは出来ているとのことでしたので、難しく考えず
`index.php`とほぼ同じ内容で`single.php`を作成しました。

しかしながら、

> 上記のsingle.phpを認識してくれずindex.phpの方をしか表示されません。

どのようにしたら、single.phpをWordPressが認識してくれるのでしょうか？

ご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたら、ご教授よろしくお願い致します。

【開発環境】
 - レンタルサーバー（CentOS 5）
 - WordPress（4.1.1）
 - PHP（5.2.16）
 - HTML
 - CSS
 - 作業環境（Windows7pro）
 - PHP編集用（NoEditor）
 - ブラウザ（FireFox）

Answer (score 1, accepted):

参考にしている情報が間違っていますね。
single.phpは固定ページではなく「投稿」です。
固定ページは通常page.phpです。
といってもテーマにもよるので、最終的にはindex.phpだけでも良い仕組みになっています。

http://wpdocs.sourceforge.jp/%E3%83%86%E3%83%B3%E3%83%97%E3%83%AC%E3%83%BC%E3%83%88%E9%9A%8E%E5%B1%A4

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございました。「page.php」を作成して試してみたのですが、やはりindex.phpの方しか認識しません。ちなみにindex.phpでも固定ページの入力内容を表示できるようですが、参考になって分かりやすいWebサイトをご存知でしょうか？

Comment: 初期インストール状態ではちゃんとpage.phpが動きますよね。
テストページも表示されますよね。

その状態からカスタマイズしたい内容を少しずつ反映しては表示確認を繰り返していくのが確実かつ近道です。

PHPだけでなくHTML、CSSについても初心者ということであればindex.phpは修正しないほうが良いです。

Comment: 続報です。色々とWordPressを触っていたらpage.php、認識するようになりました。原因は単純に私の経験および知識不足でした。